# Multiply matrix columns with decreasing elements starting by the last column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with following shape:

```
A = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]
```

Now I want starting with the last column to multiply the column with a number and then decrease the number and move to the next column.

So if we start with the number 1 and use for step 0.2 to modify all columns:

```
Anew = [1*0.6 2*0.8 3*1;
        4*0.6 5*0.8 6*1;
        7*0.6 8*0.8 9*1]
```

Or for second example we start with 0.9 with 0.1 as step and modify 3 columns:

```
B = [1  2  3  4;
     5  6  7  8;
     9  10 11 12;
     13 14 15 16]
```

And to get:

```
Bnew = [1   2*0.7  3*0.8   4*0.9;
        5   6*0.7  7*0.8   8*0.9;
        9   10*0.7 11*0.8 12*0.9;
        13  14*0.7 15*0.8 16*0.9]
```

The matrices might vary in their amount of columns, and I would like to set starting number, ending number, step number and the amount of columns I want to modify.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Also, your syntax is Python, not MATLAB. Please pick one.

Comment: Sorry I don't see your edit earlier. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing can be achieved with [broadcasted](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) element-wise multiplication in matlab R2016b and beyond.

Let's say your inputs are the matrix `A`, start value `start`, step size `step`, and number `n`. You can start by constructing the factors you want to multiply by. I am going to assume that when `n > size(A, 2)`, you want to just use the first `n` steps rather than error out:

```
k = size(A, 2);
n = min(n, k);
factors = ones(1, k);
factors(1 + k - n:end) = linspace(start - (n - 1) * step, start, n);
```

Now you can just multiply your matrix:

```
result = A .* factors;
```

This solution has the advantage of being extremely simple and fully vectorized.

If you have an older version of MATLAB, do the following instead:

```
result = A .* repmat(factors, size(A, 1), 1);
```

Or use [Tony's trick](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/02/22/scalar-expansion-and-more-take-2/):

```
result = A .* factors(ones(3, 1), :)
```

Comment: Very nice short solution.

Comment: @Zed. Thanks. Could you please fix the question using the edit button beneath it?

Comment: Is there also a modification possible to ignore the n and to leave those columns, who are not modified with elements of 0? Because the matrices vary later in the code and if n > dimension, then an error occurs.

Comment: @Zed. Good catch. I meant `min` instead of `max`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

```
count = 0;

A = randi([-10,10],4,4);

Anew = [];

for i=0.9:-0.1:0

    number_columns = 3;

    if count == number_columns

        rest = existing_columns - count;

        for i=rest:-1:1

            Anew = [(A(:,i)) Anew];

        end

        break

    end

    existing_columns = size(A,1);

    Anew = [(A(:,existing_columns-count)*i) Anew];

    count = count + 1;

end
```